# Prove that $\cup_{1<p\leq\infty} L^p([0,1])\subset L^1([0,1]) $.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Prove that $\cup_{1<p\leq\infty} L^p([0,1])\subset L^1([0,1]) $.

Let $f\in\cup_{1<p\leq\infty}L^p([0,1])$.
Then $f\in L^p([0,1])$ for some $p$. We write $\int|f|d\mu < (\int|f|^p\ )^\frac{1}{p}(\int1^q\ )^\frac{1}{q}$ since $\int|f|^p$ is finite
then $\int|f|d\mu$ is finite. Therefore $f\in L^1([0,1] )$

I feel like this proof is too simple. there should be more cases. Is this explanation enough to prove this claim?

Comment: Holders Inequality.

Comment: yeah. I used the holder Inequality.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Don't worry. However, the case that $p=\infty$ needs to be handled separately, which is also easy.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, Hoelder's inequality even holds for $p=\infty$.

Comment: Oh.$p=\infty$. Okay. I'll show that. Thank you